# AngularJs $injector Error in my App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am currently having an issue with my app breaking due to a `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error`

The full error is:

```
    Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module JobCtrl due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'JobCtrl' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/nomod?p0=JobCtrl
    at http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:69:20
    at http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:2188:31
    at ensure (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:2112:46)
    at module (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:2186:24)
    at http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:4757:36
    at forEach (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:358:34)
    at loadModules (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:4741:13)
    at http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:4758:54
    at forEach (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:358:34)
    at loadModules (http://ep-dev3/CPDManagement/app/Vendor/angular.js:4741:13)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/modulerr?
```

I have ui.bootstrap as a dependency in both my app.js and my controller. When I try to remove the dependency from my controller the application breaks. If I leave it, it runs fine but gives me issues with adding services and directives.

app.js :

```
    angular.module('app',
    [
        'JobCtrl',
        'JobSvc',
        'WebsiteCtrl',
        'WebsiteSvc',
        'myClientCtrl',
        'ClientSvc',
        'MediaCompanyCtrl',
        'MediaCompanySvc',
        'PageAlertSvc',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'Common'
    ]
);
```

controller:

```
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('JobCtrl',
            [
                'JobService',
                'WebsiteService',
                'MediaCompanyService',
                'ProductService',
                '$scope',
                '$uibModal',
                'PageAlertService',
                function (JobService, WebsiteService, MediaCompanyService,
                    ProductService, $scope, $uibModal,PageAlertService){
                                     /** Stuff in my controller **/
             }]);
```

**EDIT Showing Source**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - CPD Management Tool</title>
    <script src="~/app/Vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
{
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                @Html.ActionLink("Clear Path Direct", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
               @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
               {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Tools<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink("Media Jobs", "Index", "MediaJobs")</li>
                            <li class="text-center">Order Processing</li>
                            <li class="text-center">Media Reporting</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Clients", "Index", "Clients")</li>
                            <li class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Media Companies", "Index", "MediaCompanies")</li>
                            <li class="text-center">@Html.ActionLink("Manage Websites", "Index", "Websites")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
               }
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                }
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <!--
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - CPD Management Tool</p>
        </footer>
            -->
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <!--angular scripts-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
    <!-- ---->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: where I am bring in sources]

Why does my application run when my controller is:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('JobCtrl',
        [
            'JobService',
            'WebsiteService',
            'MediaCompanyService',
            'ProductService',
            '$scope',
            '$uibModal',
            'PageAlertService',
            function (JobService, WebsiteService, MediaCompanyService,
                ProductService, $scope, $uibModal,PageAlertService)
```

and break when I have it like:

```
angular.module('app').controller('JobCtrl',
    [
        'JobService',
        'WebsiteService',
        'MediaCompanyService',
        'ProductService',
        '$scope',
        '$uibModal',
        'PageAlertService',
        function (JobService, WebsiteService, MediaCompanyService,
            ProductService, $scope, $uibModal,PageAlertService)
```

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: you want to remove bootstrap and related things?

Comment: Can we see where you're loading your js in your html?

Comment: I want to be able to use ui.bootstrap, but I should still be able to use it if the dependency is in the app.js dependency list, right?

Comment: yes you should be able to, whats the issue?

Comment: this is one of the most common angular errors to be asked on this site, and the vast majority of the [2,768 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=angular%20%24injector%20error) are answered in one of two ways.  Either the app is declared wrong, or the dependencies are declared in the wrong order.  In your case, you should try using `angular.module('app')` rather than `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])` in your controller file.  The first (correct) is a getter, the second, (incorrect) is a setter.  Your controller should only set itself, not it's parent.

Comment: I have tried taking ui.bootstrap out of the controller and then it crashes the app giving me the aforementioned error.

Comment: @Claies Yeah, I am definitely aware of how much of a silly error this is. What I don't understand is why when I attempt to fix it (a.k.a NOT declare the app over by adding dependencies again) it gives me the injector error. But when I have it as I do above, it runs fine.

Comment: if you have fixed the code as I mention in my comments, then the next step will be to use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.  the `.min.js` is for production, and does not produce clear errors.  Using the full file will give descriptive errors.

Comment: also, "taking out ui.bootstrap" could mean many things, since you have it declared in 3 locations.  you should be very clear about the ***current state*** of your code when presenting an error.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, if I have caused any. The above is my current code, the error that is above is what happens when I take out ui.bootstrap from the Controller. I do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: so have you tried what I suggested in my first comment??

Comment: Yes and I am now using Angular.js instead of Angular.min.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136999/discussion-between-ddelgro-and-claies).

Comment: you have `JobCtrl` listed as the first **module** to be *imported* in app.js, but `JobCtrl` isn't a module, it is a controller.  Remove this first line in your app.js.

Comment: for that matter, you only need to import services if they are declared in a different module, and that would be the module you are importing, not the service itself.

Comment: You fixed it. I didn't know you weren't supposed to import all your controllers and services into the app.js. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was that I was importing all my controllers and services in the app module (app.js). Thank you @Claies for pointing this out to me.

***Wrong:***

```
      angular.module('app',
    [
        'JobCtrl',
        'JobSvc',
        'WebsiteCtrl',
        'WebsiteSvc',
        'myClientCtrl',
        'ClientSvc',
        'MediaCompanyCtrl',
        'MediaCompanySvc',
        'PageAlertSvc',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'Common'
    ]
);
```

**Right:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```